# Creating oracle JOB for my stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create an Oracle Job for `c_insert_ship_confirm_start`.

```
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"CRCTFDC11XRQA"."SHIP_CONFIRM_JOB"',
            job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
            job_action => 'c_insert_ship_confirm_start(1000,FDC,1,0)',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP('09-MAR-16 02.41.43.451000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=FRI,MON,SAT,SUN,THU,TUE,WED;BYMINUTE=5',
            end_date => NULL,
            job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
            enabled => false,
            auto_drop => true,
            comments => 'SHIP_CONFIRM_JOB IN EVERY 5 MINS',
            credential_name => NULL,
            destination_name => NULL);
END;
```

Stored procedure for reference::

```
create or replace procedure c_insert_ship_confirm_start
(
    p_commit_frequency in number default 1000,
    p_whse             in varchar2,
    p_debug_flag       in number default 0,
    p_rc               out number
)
```

while creating JOB Oracle throwing error::

> ORA-27452: %s is an invalid name for a database object

Answer (score 1):

Arguments are not supported with `stored_procedure` job type. [Reference: Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#i1000363)

Use `plsql_block`

```
BEGIN
    sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name            => '"CRCTFDC11XRQA"."SHIP_CONFIRM_JOB"',
                                  job_type            => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                                  job_action          => 'begin c_insert_ship_confirm_start(1000,''FDC'',1,0); end;',
                                  number_of_arguments => 0,
                                  start_date          => to_timestamp('09-MAR-16 02.41.43.451000000 PM',
                                                                      'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
                                  repeat_interval     => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=FRI,MON,SAT,SUN,THU,TUE,WED;BYMINUTE=5',
                                  end_date            => NULL,
                                  job_class           => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
                                  enabled             => FALSE,
                                  auto_drop           => TRUE,
                                  comments            => 'SHIP_CONFIRM_JOB IN EVERY 5 MINS',
                                  credential_name     => NULL,
                                  destination_name    => NULL);
END;
/
```